# Why is my search bar functioning improperly

Tags: javascript, dom-events

**I dont understand why the results for search is not popping up,can you help me out with that,Thanks !:)**

````
console.log(searchForm.firstElementChild);
searchForm.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  let searchValue = e.target.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;
  //console.log(searchValue);
  let searchSpace = document.getElementsByTagName('section');
  Array.from(searchSpace).forEach(section=>{
    let searchedTaskName = section.firstElementChild.textContent;
    if(searchedTaskName.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())){
      section.style.display="block";
    }
    else{
      section.style.display="none";
    }
  })
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is supposed to be a comment but due to low reps I had to put this as an answer.

Can you share the html snippet as well? And a description of what you are trying to achieve?

The js snippet is not enough to answer the question.